# After clonning ES warns "[Eslint] expected linebreaks to be lf but found crlf." Should I set GIT differently, or ESlint?

Tags: git, newline, eslint, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I forked and cloned a JS npm library and opened it in Visual Studio Code. At the end of each line there was an error with the following message:

```
[Eslint] expected linebreaks to be lf but found crlf. (line break-style)
```

I use a Windows 10 computer and I don't get this error on my own code. I guess the library was written in Linux and that is the source of the problem, but shouldn't Git replace line-change somehow? 
The question is: how should I solve this problem? Should I stop Eslint from presenting this error, or should I change the settings of my git client (Source-Tree). If the latter, which settings should I choose?

Perhaps related: When using Powershell and running the command 'npm install' I got an error. But when I run this command on Shell on Ubuntu on Windows 'npm install' worked.

Comment: You may have to tell git how to work with line endings.  What do you see with `git config --list | grep autocrlf` ?